# Java Herencia abstraccion. Como gestionar los atributos fijos para cada subclase?

Tags: java, herencia, buenas-prácticas, polimorfismo, clase-abstracta

Tengo las siguientes indicaciones:

[image: Indicaciones_salarios_abogados_segun_tipo]
Editado: Se agrego la clase Abogado Junior

Notese que solo los valores de monto fijo mensual y bono mensual son variables entre las subclases.

**ADEMAS:** Solo el abogado Junior posee casos de apoyo y recibe un bono 200 por cada caso apoyo

**La pregunta es:** ¿Es correcto llamar a valores fijos en el constructor desde las subclases? ¿Es buena practica o de que forma podria gestionar esos valores que en un futuro podrian cambiar?

```java
abstract class Abogado {
    protected String nombres;
    protected String apellidos;
    protected String status;
    protected int numHijos;
    protected int aniosExperiencia;
    protected float montoFijoMensual;
    protected float bonoPorCasosCargo;
    protected int numCasosCargo;

    public Abogado(){}

    public Abogado(String nombres, String apellidos, String status, int numHijos, int aniosExperiencia, float montoFijoMensual, float bonoPorCasosCargo, int numCasosCargo) {
        this.nombres = nombres;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.status = status;
        this.numHijos = numHijos;
        this.aniosExperiencia = aniosExperiencia;
        this.montoFijoMensual = montoFijoMensual;
        this.bonoPorCasosCargo = bonoPorCasosCargo;
        this.numCasosCargo = numCasosCargo;
    }
    
    public float calcularSueldoMensual(){
        float sueldoMensual = this.montoFijoMensual + this.bonoPorCasosCargo * this.numCasosCargo;
        return sueldoMensual;
    }
}
```

Mientras la subclase AbogadoSenior

```java
public class AbogadoSenior extends Abogado {
    
    public AbogadoSenior(String nombres, String apellidos, int numHijos, int aniosExperiencia, int numCasosCargo) {
        super(nombres, apellidos, "Senior", numHijos, aniosExperiencia, 4000, 2000, numCasosCargo);
    }
}
```

Y la subclase Abogado Socio

```java
public class AbogadoSocio extends Abogado {

    public AbogadoSocio(String nombres, String apellidos, int numHijos, int aniosExperiencia, int numCasosCargo) {
        super(nombres, apellidos, "Senior", numHijos, aniosExperiencia, 10000, 10000, numCasosCargo);
    } 
}
```

Comment: No veo razón para crear clases especializadas basándose en los valores de los atributos. Más bien `tipoAbogado` debería ser un atributo más. Con respecto a donde manejar  los valores fijos, debería hacerse en un lugar externo a la clase `Abogado` usando una condición según el tipo `if(abogado.getTipo() == 'senior') // hacer algo`

Comment: Entiendo lo de crear un atributo tipoAbogado. Pero podrias brindar mas detalles de como o un ejemplo de: "Con respecto a donde manejar los valores fijos, debería hacerse en un lugar externo a la clase Abogado "

Comment: Podría ser una función que reciba el tipo de abogado a crear y retorne una instancia con los valores establecidos para ese tipo. `static Abogado crear(String tipo) { if(tipo.equals("senior")) return new Abogado(...argumentos para abogado senior)`

Comment: "Es correcto llamar a valores fijos desde el constructor desde las subclases" Para tu ejercicio, es correcto. En el mundo real, nada de esto es correcto. Las reglas de negocio (por ejemplo estos valores) deberian estar en un lugar donde los actualices facil, como una base de datos...  ;)

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con lo que dice @gbianchi, esto se representaría en una fuente de datos (base de datos u otra) y convendría crear una clase `Sueldo` donde expreses la lógica a seguir. En esa clase, según el tipo de empleado, asignarías los montos correspondientes.

Answer (score 1):

Respondiendo estrictamente a tu pregunta y no solo para este caso en especifico, existe la Ley de Demeter (una flexible/weak y la otra estricta/strong). En ellas se especifica que, dependiendo de tu caso particular podrías o no acoplarte en una herencia a los atributos del padre.

Si no te acoplas a ellos tendrías mas flexibilidad y tus subclases no sufrirían de los cambios en la clase padre. Si te acoplas a ellos tu trabajo en las subclases seria mucho mas fácil puesto que cada clase individual puede trabajar con ellos de la forma que quiera.

Todo depende de tu caso particular, si tu jerarquía de herencia no va a crecer y se va a mantener estable puedes acoplarte a ellos, si ves que es un punto critico que tiende a cambiar deberias no acoplarte y aplicar otras técnicas que te permitan extensibilidad.

#### Data Clumps

Veo que tus clases tienen muchos atributos, este es un smell code del libro de Refactoring de Martin Fowler llamado [data clumps](https://blog.susomejias.dev/blog/code-smell-data-clumps). Esto te esta generando que tengas constructores con demasiados atributos y por tanto, código difícil de leer.

Te recomendaría crear clases auxiliares para que no tengas que trabajar así, a la larga estas clases ganaran comportamientos y hará que tu código sea mas fácil de mantener.

#### Herencia

Desconozco si tus subclases tienen otros métodos o atributos que justifiquen una herencia, con el código que publicaste no  la estas aplicando de forma correcta (debido a que las subclases ni se especializan, ni extienden el concepto del que heredan). Hacer jerarquías de este tipo solo incrementa la complejidad y no aprovecha los mecanismos de Polimorfismo (rompe el principio de substitucion de Liskov), a la larga hace que tu código se vuelva difícil de mantener.

Para solucionarlo, podrías crear un Enumerado en el cual colocas el tipo de abogado. Basado en el tipo de abogado podrías establecer un salario u otro. Con esto ya no necesitas del mecanismo de Herencia y a la vez puedes conocer el tipo de abogado con el que estas trabajando.

Sin embargo, si la herencia esta justificada y sabes que los tipos de abogados incrementaran puedes volver a la clase Abogado abstracta y colocarle un método abstracto para calcular el salario. Con esto cada subclase tiene que especificar como se calcula su salario y si agregas mas clases solo tienes que crearla e implementar este método. De esta forma cada subclase se encargara de decir sus valores particulares. Para tu problema creo que es un poco exagerado implementar esto (YAGNI), sin embargo, es importante conocerlo, quizás lo podrías implementar y te ahorras problemas a futuro.

#### Referencias

- https://medium.com/vattenfall-tech/the-law-of-demeter-by-example-fd7adbf0c324#e62a
- https://blog.susomejias.dev/blog/code-smell-data-clumps
- http://www.btechsmartclass.com/java/java-forms-of-inheritance.html
- https://www.oodesign.com/open-close-principle

Comment: La respuesta no es mala, pero es solo una enumeracion de cosas que podrian o no ser inherentes a la pregunta. Hay cosas totalemente opinables (por ejemplo, no hay data clumps, es una clase con otras dos que la heredan) y si fueramos a las buenas practicas, toda la info deberia venir de una db..

Comment: Hablando de buenas practicas donde colocaria la sentencia SQL (por ejemplo) para obtener el monto a pagarle y el bono en el controlador o el modelo?

Answer (score 0):

En extensión de lo que comenta **@Lobos** ->

Si lo único que diferencia a un **Senior** de un **Socio** son los montos para calcular su sueldo: No es necesario que crees las clases *AbogadoSenior* y *AbogadoSocio*, basta con que el método **calcularSueldoMensual** realice la operación:

```
montoFijoMensual + (bonoPorCasosCargo * numCasosCargo).
```

Por otra parte, también te recomiendan que tanto el dato ***montoFijoMensual*** como el ***bonoPorCasosCargo*** no los manejes hardcode (dentro del código) sino que los almacenes en alguna fuente externa que sea fácil de modificar (sin que tengas que recompilar tu código fuente) por ejemplo un archivo properties externo o si ya cuentas con una base de datos que la utilices.